unable to attach payment method to payment Intent in stripe react native with medusajs backend
i am trying to attach payment method with payment intent in stripe in react native.
But i am getting no payment method in stripe, only payment intent is available without payment method and it remains incomplete.
on entring the card details, i press the button for "Continue to Review", which triggers the below function .
I am using CardField for car details UI.
  const handleReviewOrderSubmit = async (value) => {

    if (value === "stripe") {
      const paymentSession = state.cart.payment_session;
      const billingDetails = state.cart.billing_address;
      const clientSecret = paymentSession.data.client_secret;

      await confirmPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: "card",
          billing_details: billingDetails,
        },
      }).then(({ error, paymentIntent }) => {
        if (error) {
          alert("Payment failed", error);
        }
        if (paymentIntent) {
          alert("Payment successful");
          
        }
      });
    }
  };

please let me know the right method to update the payment method to payment Intent.
additional info:
The backend is working fine, since i am using the same backend for processing on web application of the same project.

I think you might need to check this guide. Although Stripe no longer recommends using this, I think you should migrate to the PaymentElement.

i have actually used this particular link for React Native https://docs.stripe.com/payments/card-element?platform=react-native. And the corresponding SDK for web platform https://docs.stripe.com/payments/card-element?platform=web is actually working on the web application. With payment Element, it requires a new endpoint by the name of payment-sheet , which i will have to make it on the backend. But I was thinking, if this is working on web, it should work on react-native also . Else I will have to resort to paymentElement by making a new API endpoint by the name payment-sheet.

I actually tried first by the payment Element, but the issue was that payment method was not getting attached to the payment intent, then i discovered, it needs a new API endpoint, so for going a easier route, i switched to cardField for react native.

what do you mean it's not attached to the payment intent?

the payment method was null, checked it in stripe logs. but later found an error in the confirmPayment, I was just specifying 'type:'Card' instead of 'paymentMethodType:'Card' and for address corrected it to 'paymentethodData: {billingAddress} . tried it with these modifications, and payment method was done . It moved to Visa Page, checked it on stripe logs also. So that issue was resolved

But then due to difference in currencies, I need to specify 'description' as part of 'paymentIntent 'to make the payment  successful. And that custom modification I need to do in Medusajs backend to include description as part of paymentIntent.
